# Can we migrate to Lightning and keep some users in classic?

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, classic

We have two types of users in our organisation: Type A use objects with page layouts with embedded Visualforce pages that are not compatible with Lightning. Type B users (role and profile distinct from Type A) use just the standard objects with normal page layouts.

If we migrate to Lightning org then can I have the Type B users use the Lightning interface and leverage the benefits and the Type A users use the classic so that they can access the Visualforce pages without Lightning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can set this on the Lightning Experience settings

> Setup-->Lightning Experience.

On this section: **Decide Who Can Use Lightning Experience**

If you click on **Select User** on the **Switch Users to Lightning Experience** section you can click on the users the will have access to the **Lightning Experience**

Comment: Or even create a permission set and assign it to specific user if you want to audit at the end of the quarter on who the lightning users were.https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trails/lex_admin_migration/modules/lex_migration_introduction/units/lex_migration_introduction_administration